# Multi Model data set Visualization Python

Tags: python, bigdata, visualization, graphs, research

I have a data-set with two variable frequency values as given below

```
col[0],col[1],col[2],col[3]
val1, 23, 34, key1
val1, 23, 56, key2
val1, 23, 54, kay3
val2, 34, 76, kay1
val2, 34, 87, key4
val3, 90, 23, key2
```

Real Datasets

```
Reduction_Paris 957 228 #promos
Reduction_Paris 957 214 #promos
Reduction_Paris 957 181 #paris
Reduction_Paris 957 175 #promos
CNNsWorld   361 156 #breakingnews
CNNsWorld   361 156 #gamedev
CNNsWorld   361 156 #paris
CNNsWorld   361 156 #parisattack
FollowParisNews 705 131 #france
FollowParisNews 705 131 #news
FollowParisNews 705 131 #paris
Reduction_Paris 957 128 #promos
Reduction_Paris 957 128 #paris
FollowParisNews 705 128 #france
FollowParisNews 705 128 #news
FollowParisNews 705 128 #paris
FollowParisNews 705 125 #france
FollowParisNews 705 125 #news
FollowParisNews 705 125 #paris
Reduction_Paris 957 123 #paris
FollowParisNews 705 119 #france
```

The data set has more than 1000s of rows `val` is a string variable and `key` is also string. where as the `col[1]` and `col[2]` are the frequencies respectively of `val` and `key`. The `val` and `key` are connected to each other several values are connected to several keys.

I am trying to plot two kinds of graphs.

1. A graph to show pair inverse cumulative distribution function (ccdf). `col[1]` and `col[2]` are to be considered in this case. When it is only one value we can very well plot ccdf as individual but as a pair I have no idea how to get the distribution plots.
2. A connected graph to show the connection relationship between the `val col[0]` and `key col[3]`. I tried using `Cytoscape` and chose key as node and val as edge but I do not get the graph that I am looking for. Any solution on how I can show the relationship between the two ?

May be something like this kind of solution I am looking for, Cluster of Keywords col[3] and the col[0] connected to them.Either of the one type of graph.

[image: Image_2]

[image: Image_1]
I am comfortable with python so any suggestion in that area will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Have you consider [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library? please show the sample real data so that I can process it.

Comment: @AlexanderYau Pls check the description with real data part. I did try Pandas but my data does not have headers and putting the column values and reading them in array is a bit troublesome. But my main question here how can use two values i.e. x, y both together and show how they are distributed as pair? and how can show relationship between them ?